# Why does the text on my button not appear?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a text editor and I'm adding a navbar but the text on FileBtn doesn't appear.

```
from tkinter import *

##############################################

# Constants
width = 800
height = 450

##############################################

# Window Creation
Window = Tk()
Window.geometry(F'{width}x{height}')
Window.title("TextWrite")

##############################################

# Navbar Creation
Navbar = Frame(Window, width = width, height = 25, bg = "#141414")
Navbar.place(x = 0, y = 0)

# File Options Creation

def OpenFileOptions():
    FileOptions.place(x = 0, y = 25)

FileBtn = Button(Window, width = 10, height = 25, text = "File", bg = "#171717", fg = "white", command = OpenFileOptions)
FileBtn.place(x = 0, y = 0)

FileOptions = Frame(Window, width = 10, height = 50)
FileOptions.place(x = -1000, y = 0)

##############################################

# Text Input Creation
Input = Text(Window, width = width, height = 425, bg = "#202020", fg = "white")
Input.place(x = 0, y = 25)

Window.mainloop()
```

I searched for my problem but nothing I found seemed to fix it.
This is the first time I have encountered this error, and I have no clue why it happens.

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you don't create the other UI widgets?

Comment: Your text widget hide your button.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel when I took it out of the navbar it became taller and I could see the text.

Comment: @Corralien But I have my text widget's position set to where the navbar ends. And even if I delete my text widget the text still doesn't appear.

Comment: Don't you put your Button into Navbar rather than Window?

Comment: @Corralien Yes I do, I didn't notice that earlier, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I can see the "File" text of the button if the `Text` widget is removed.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you've set the height of the button to 25 *lines* tall. The `width` and `height` for some widgets -- including buttons -- is in number of characters, not pixels. Tkinter will center the text in the widget, so the text was very far down and out of view.

You can actually see this if you remove the text widget. You'll see that the button is very tall and the button label is centered in the button but roughly in the middle of the widget. (note: the following screenshot was taken on a Mac, which doesn't support changing the background color of buttons)

[image: screenshot without the text widget]

If you remove the `height` attribute altogether or set `height` to `1`, you'll see the text, though you might have to also change the colors.

---

If you're just now learning tkinter, I strongly encourage you to use `pack` and/or `grid` rather than `place`. There's a slight learning curve, but it's much easier to make GUIs that are responsive and that make optimal use of the window size. `place` is best for very unique circumstances rather than as a general purpose tool.

Comment: It is not the main issue because I can see the "File" text of the button if the `Text` widget (`Input`) is removed.

Comment: @acw1668: you can see it, yes, but it's not where the  user expects it to be. And the root cause is not because the text is covering it but because they've misconfigured the button in my opinion. Given that they want to see a text widget, the solution is to fix the button, not remove the text widget. However, I'll edit the answer to mention the fact that it would be visible if they removed the text widget.

Answer (score 0):

> but the text on FileBtn doesn't appear

No need to change value. In line 37, change this `y=25` to `y=400`. Should be like this: `Input.place(x = 0, y = 400)`

Screenshot:

[image]